# Http Request not carried out when Angular app is included in java backend

Tags: angular

we are developing an Angular User Interface for a legacy app that runs with Java backend and GWT frontend. I am experiencing the issue that a certain http request is only done when I runthe angular app in standalone mode on port 4200 but as soon as I compile it as element .js file and load it in my legacy app, this http request does not show up int he Network tab of the browser.

Heres the class where the http request takes place:

```
import { Credentials } from 'src/app/credentials';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { merge, Observable, shareReplay, Subject, switchMap } from "rxjs";
import { CREDENTIALS } from "../app.module";
import { IOwlUser, IOwlUserResponse } from "./interfaces/owl-user.interface";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class OwlUsersService {
  public readonly users$: Observable<any>;
  private readonly reload$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient, @Inject(CREDENTIALS) private readonly credentials: Credentials) {
    const url = `/rest/Contacts`;

    const users$ = this.http
      .get<IOwlUserResponse[]>(url, { withCredentials: true });

    this.users$ = merge(
      users$,
      this.reload$.pipe(switchMap(() => users$))
    ).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  public loadUsers(): void {
    this.reload$.next();
  }

  public filterUser(owlUsers: IOwlUserResponse[]): IOwlUser[] {
    return owlUsers.reduce((acc: IOwlUser[], curr: IOwlUserResponse) => {
      curr.Users?.forEach((ele: any) => {
        acc.push(ele);
      });
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is an impossible question to debug given the information as so much could be causing this issue.  I would try to subscribe to this.users$ in the service constructor.  If it still doesn't work and *you know for sure the constructor is being hit* then my feeling is that you have an HttpInterceptor that's causing an issue.  Otherwise there is some other condition that's causing a subscription not to be made.

Comment: the constructor is definitively hit, i added some console.logs to be sure.